# Font error while migrating from API 25 to 26

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

Currently I am migrating my project from **targetSdkVersion 25 to 26**
Here is my app.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17

        targetSdkVersion 26

        multiDexEnabled true

        versionCode versionMajor * 100000 + versionMinor * 1000 + versionPatch * 10 + versionHotfix
        versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"
    }
}
```

But while upgrading I am facing this error repeatedly:

```
String types not allowed (at 'font' with value 'Knockout-31').
Message{kind=ERROR, text=String types not allowed (at 'font' with value 'Knockout-31')., sources=[D:\Qdoba-Android\qdoba-android-app\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\internal\debug\values\values.xml:2466:21-32], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}
```

Here is a snippet of **fonts folder**:

[image]

Please help.

Comment: how are you setting fonts ?

Comment: fontPath="fonts/Knockout-70.otf"

Comment: @kgandroid rename your font as `Knockout_70.otf` Remove **-(minus)** and use **_(underscore)**

Comment: Ok,i will try it,but it was running in api version 25.Why so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:Update the gradle plugin above 3.0

Answer (score 0):

According to Android Documentation [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml)

> Android 8.0 (API level 26) introduces a new feature, Fonts in XML,
>   which lets you use fonts as resources. You can add the font file in
>   the res/font/ folder to bundle fonts as resources. These fonts are
>   compiled in your R file and are automatically available in Android
>   Studio. You can access the font resources with the help of a new
>   resource type, font. For example, to access a font resource, use
>   @font/myfont, or R.font.myfont.

So you have to move all your fonts in to font folder inside the res.
If you cannot find a font directory, create a new 'font' directory in res directory.

use a font in your view like below,

```
android:fontFamily="@font/Knockout-31"
```

Another way to use a custom font family without using attribute android:fontFamily = "..."

1. For text views

   ```
   public class customFont extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{

   public customFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
       super(context, attrs, defStyle);
       init();
   }

   public customFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
       init();
   }

   public customFont(Context context) {
       super(context);
       init();
   }

   public void init() {
       Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "Knockout-31.otf");
       setTypeface(tf ,1);

   }
   }
   ```

Your text view with custom font

```
    <example.com.example.customFont
         android:id="@+id/textView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Text View" />
```

Thanks

Comment: I saw this answer in SO already.But is it absolutely necessary to move fonts to res in api 26? Some other projects are still running with api version 26 with font kept in asset folder

Comment: If you want to use android:fontFamily = ".." you have to move it to font folder, but there are alternative ways to do this without moving. But you will not be able to use android:fontFamily = "..."